# Sort list by greatest calculated value c#

Tags: c#, sorting

Hello folks I am facing a challenge, I have this list:

```
ITEM3 ----- 2,311 € ----- 89 PCS ----- 03:55:02.933
PIECE2 ----- 22,20 € ----- 55 PCS ----- 07:45:04.686
ATRIBUTEZ ----- 6,435 € ----- 100 PCS ----- 07:59:07.751
```

And I want to sort all items by most expensive buy, so buy amount is calculated by multiplicating euro value and pcs value together
So desired output would be:

```
PIECE2 ----- 22,20 € ----- 55 PCS ----- 07:45:04.686 1. Amount:1221€

ATRIBUTEZ ----- 6,435 € ----- 100 PCS ----- 07:59:07.751 2. Amount:643,5€

ITEM3 ----- 2,311 € ----- 89 PCS ----- 03:55:02.933 3. Amount:205,679€
```

Following code I have as of now:

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<string> mylist = new List<string>(new string[] { "ITEM3 ----- 2,311 € ----- 89 PCS ----- 03:55:02.933",
"PIECE2 ----- 22,20 € ----- 55 PCS ----- 07:45:04.686",
"ATRIBUTEZ ----- 6,435 € ----- 100 PCS ----- 07:59:07.751"
 });

            listBox1.DataSource = mylist;
        }
```

I appreciate any help, thanks to anyone here.

Comment: Is that really a list string or do you have a list of concrete objects that we can work against? Your first step should be to parse that string into some sort of strongly typed record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would tacke this problem in 2 steps: First, parse those strings into a class, so we can operate on it. After that, we can calculate the `Amount` and order it.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> mylist = new List<string>(new string[] 
        { 
            "ITEM3 ----- 2,311 € ----- 89 PCS ----- 03:55:02.933",
            "PIECE2 ----- 22,20 € ----- 55 PCS ----- 07:45:04.686",
            "ATRIBUTEZ ----- 6,435 € ----- 100 PCS ----- 07:59:07.751"
         });
        //convert your list of strings into a list of Items
        var listOfItems = mylist
           .Select(x => new Item(x))
           //order by desc according to Amount
           .OrderByDescending(x => x.Amount);

        //do whatever we want with it.
        foreach (var item in listOfItems)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{item.Name} --- {item.Amount}");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}

public class Item
{
    public Item(string source)
    {
        //split the string and assign the values
        var values = source.Split(" ", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        Name = values[0].ToString();
        Price = Convert.ToDecimal(values[2].ToString());
        Pieces = Convert.ToInt32(values[5].ToString());
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int Pieces { get; set; }
    //automatically calculate the Amount
    public decimal Amount => Price * Pieces;
}
```

Please note, that the conversion from a string in the constructor is very naive and not very robust. I am simply assuming, that the string is following a pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regex. First we match required patterns. And then we remove euro symbol and empty space. We parse it to double using current culture. And we have the ordered prices.

```cs
var orderedList = mylist
                .Select(i => Regex.Match(i, @"\d+\,\d+\s€"))
                .Select(m => m.Value)
                .Select(m => m.Replace(" €", ""))
                .Select(m => Convert.ToDouble(m))
                .OrderByDescending(val => val)
                .ToList();
```

And to get all items:

```
var germanCulture = new CultureInfo("de-DE");

var orderedList = mylist
    .Select(i => new
    {
        Match = Regex.Match(i, @"\d+\,\d+\s€").Value,
        Item = i
    })
    .OrderByDescending(i => 
        Convert.ToDouble(i.Match.Replace(" €", ""), germanCulture))
    .Select(i => i.Item)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: not working, giving me only `6435
2311
2220 ` @ndogac

Comment: @qwertzu2412 Commas in your prices may be problem, if you are using a machine where default is `InvariantCulture`, you should use `Convert.ToDouble(m, yourCulture)`. You can use German culture for commas.

Comment: @qwertzu2412 I've updated the answer to get all items with specific culture as well.